# MSBuild error when creating a build definition in TFS 2013

Tags: tfs, build, msbuild, build-definition

I am trying to create a build definition so that I can publish the changes that I have made from my database project to SQL server. Whenever I queue new build, I always get this error:

```
Exception Message: MSBuild error 1 has ended this build. You can find more specific information about the cause of this error in above messages. (type BuildProcessTerminateException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at System.Activities.Statements.Throw.Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
   at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
   at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)
```

When I create my build, its more likely the defaults I did not change any configurations specially in the Process section. When I check the drop folder as well, this is the error log:

```
Build started 4/25/2016 1:16:15 AM.
Project "C:\Builds\2\Manufacturing Intelligence\defaultbuild\src\TFS\Database1.sln" on node 1 (default targets).
ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
 Building solution configuration "Debug|Any CPU".
Project "C:\Builds\2\Manufacturing Intelligence\defaultbuild\src\TFS\Database1.sln" (1) is building "C:\Builds\2\Manufacturing Intelligence\defaultbuild\src\TFS\Database1\Database1.sqlproj" (2) on node 1 (default targets).
PrepareForBuild:
  Creating directory "obj\Debug\".
GenerateSqlTargetFrameworkMoniker:
Skipping target "GenerateSqlTargetFrameworkMoniker" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.`
`CoreCompile:
  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\amd64\Csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702 /nostdlib+ /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:DEBUG;TRACE /highentropyva+ /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\mscorlib.dll" /debug+ /debug:full /optimize- /out:obj\Debug\Database1.dll /subsystemversion:6.00 /target:library /warnaserror- /utf8output "C:\Users\svc_TFS\AppData\Local\Temp\.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.SqlClrAttributes.cs"
SqlBuild:`
 ` Creating a model to represent the project...
Done Building Project "C:\Builds\2\Manufacturing Intelligence\defaultbuild\src\TFS\Database1\Database1.sqlproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
Done Building Project "C:\Builds\2\Manufacturing Intelligence\defaultbuild\src\TFS\Database1.sln" (default targets) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)
Time Elapsed 00:00:02.09
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you build it successfully with your local environment? 0 warning and 0 error, this may be the  environment problem. You must make sure the environment of build server are same with local.

Comment: i dont have visual studio or TFS installed on my machine where SQL server is at... if thats what you meant by local environment @Patrick-MSFT

Answer (score 0):

I used to have the same experience. There's something stucked the build. And it's also not work for any others build definition.

For my situation, finally reinstall the build agent. The issued solved.